# Access violation in Release Mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, access-violation

I get an access violation error in release mode, but not debug mode.

The error occurs when I try to close a file which was opened to read data from. This is the code:

```
FILE *file;
GLubyte *transferFunctionData = NULL;
transferFunctionData = new GLubyte(size);

if ( (file = fopen(fileName, "rb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Cannot open file.\n");
    exit(1);
}

if ( fread(transferFunctionData, sizeof(GLubyte), size, file) != size)
{
    if (feof(file))
         printf("Premature end of file.");
    else
        printf("File read error.");

    exit(1);
}

fclose(file);
```

What is interesting is that it changes the values in a pointer to a vector of pointers. Not sure if, I'm saying that correctly, this is the data container

```
vector<CustomObject*> *data;
```

In Visual Studio, I add a watch for this container. When the program tries to close the file, in the above code, it invalidates all the values stored in the container, and crashes.

Both sets of code are not related, in are not even part of the same object, so this suggests to me that the heap is getting corrupted at some stage.

But why only in release mode, is this due to release mode optimizing the code, which debug mode does not?

Comment: This usually means you failed to initialize a variable (in debug it will have a default value in release it will have a random value). Check the warnings generated by the compiler (after you raise the warning level)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should use either

```
transferFunctionData = new GLubyte[size];
```

if you want allocate array of GLubytes or

```
fread(transferFunctionData, sizeof(GLubyte), 1, file)
```

if you want to allocate and read one. Right now you are allocating one GLubyte and reading size, overwriting unallocated memory

Comment: You mean when initializing transferFunctionData set it to new `GLubyte(size)` as opposed to NULL which I'm doing now?

Comment: no - assuming that you are trying to allocate array of GLudata (transferFunctionData = new GLubyte(size);)- you made an error and have used () instead of []. new() is a syntax of allocating one element and calling an initializer. You need to allocate array instead

Comment: Ah of course! That was pretty silly of me! Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's enough to enable /EHa option in Release project settings (likely it's enabled in Debug). See **Project Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Modify the Enable C++ Exceptions to "Yes With SEH Exceptions"**. That's it!

See details here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5(v=vs.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1deeycx5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Comment: You totally swiped this from another answer, but it's still useful so I'm upvoting ;)

Comment: I actually had "Runtime Library" changed to "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" on the same screen in order to fix this issue in Release mode.